# If-loop for small console game

Tags: c#, if-statement

Hopefully you can help me! I have drawn a blank with this. 
I am making a small console game. I am entirely new to c#, so maybe its a dumbfound question.
Ex:

If you play Ashe, and you go against Brand - I want ashe to win. I feel like i need and if-else loop but I need help writting it.

Thank you!!

```
class Champ
        {
            public int Health { get; set; }
            public string Ult { get; set; }
            public int Victories { get; set; }
        }

        static public void SoloFightChamps()
        {
            var Ashe = new Champ();
            var Brand = new Champ();
            var Annie = new Champ();
            var Braum = new Champ();

            Ashe.Health = 100;
            Ashe.Ult = "Ranger";

            Brand.Health = 100;
            Brand.Ult = "Assasin";

            Annie.Health = 100;
            Annie.Ult = "Fire";

            Braum.Health = 100;
            Braum.Ult = "Warrior";


            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to fight!");
            Console.ReadLine();

            var Battle = new Task(() => {
                for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 3; ctr++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" In battle {0}", ctr);

                    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

//Code that makes Ranger win over Assasin


                }
            }
        );

            Battle.Start();
            Battle.Wait();



        }
```

Comment: How do you define _win_?

Comment: I don't want to write a full scale solution to your task, but I want to give you some hints. First you need to pick two opponents from the four defined. For this you need to store your _Champ_ in a list and then use a Random instance to select the two. Once you have the two warriors then compare the Ult property to decide if the battle has already a winner. If not throw the dice (ie, use again the Random instace) to find who wins, increment the winner counter

Comment: This is just a trace for you to follow. Try to split the work in subtasks (make a list, use the random class, compare the properties, etc) and then come back when you have some actual code that gives you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example of how you could make the battle.

```
var Battle = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 3; ctr++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" In battle {0}", ctr);

                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

                //Code that makes Ranger win over Assasin
                Console.WriteLine("{0} attack {1}", Ashe.Ult, Brand.Ult);

                Random random = new Random();
                var attack = random.Next(20, 30);
                Brand.Health -= attack;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Damaged {1} by {2}", Ashe.Ult, Brand.Ult, attack);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Health: {1}",Brand.Ult, Brand.Health);

                Console.WriteLine("{0} attack {1}",Brand.Ult, Ashe.Ult);
                attack = random.Next(5, 10);
                Ashe.Health -= attack;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Damaged {1} by {2}",Brand.Ult, Ashe.Ult,attack);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Health: {1}", Ashe.Ult, Ashe.Health);

                Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
            }

            if(Ashe.Health > Brand.Health)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} wins", Ashe.Ult);
                Ashe.Victories++;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} wins", Brand.Ult);
                Brand.Victories++;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

At each loop iteration we select a random number.

The Ranger gets better odds then the Assassin.

We then subtract the random attack value from their Health.

After three battles - by no surprise the champ with most Health wins - in this case will always be the Ranger.

Another way of doing it would be to have more properties in your class:

```
    class Champ
    {
        public int Health { get; set; }
        public string Ult { get; set; }
        public string PowerAttack { get; set; }
        public string LowerAttack { get; set; }
        public string Stamina { get; set; }
        public int Victories { get; set; }
    }
```

Power attack and lower attack might make things more interesting.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yesterday when I was waiting I some more members, aswell as a generator for a random opponent. I will definetly alter your code example and use it! But this is amazing, i was totally blank on how to go further. Thank you!

Comment: @KatrineMiraArndtLind I am glad you have found it useful :-)